# Wrong value in php math captcha form

Tags: php, captcha

The following match captcha form is not giving correct. The output is coming as "Captcha is incorrect!" in both the cases of correct value as well as in correct values entered. I have tried but unable to find the solution. The source codes are given below:
I am using PHP 5.3.6 - and I am doubt due to PHP5.3.6 it is not giving correct values.

If i enter correct math value, it is giving: **"Captcha is incorrect!"**

If I enter wrong math value, it is giving: **"Captcha is incorrect!"**

**FORM.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<form action="check.php" method="post">';
$rand_int1 = substr(mt_rand(),0,1);
$rand_int2 = substr(mt_rand(),0,1);
$cap_ans = $rand_int1 + $rand_int2;
$_SESSION['cap_ans'] = $cap_ans;
echo 'What is '.$rand_int1.' + '.$rand_int2.' ?<br>
<input type="text" name="cap_inp">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>';
?>
```

**CHECK.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$cap_inp = $_POST['cap_inp'];
$cap_ans = $_SESSION['cap_ans'];

if($cap_inp != $cap_ans) {
    echo 'Captcha is incorrect!';
}
else {
    echo 'Captcha is correct, congratulations! :)';
}
?>
```

Can any body help me / suggest the correct code please?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong.  The only two things I can think of are session_start() is failing (which usually happens if you send any output at all before calling it because it can't work if the headers are already sent), or that you're failing to clear out old values for the answer.

Comment: yeah, its just working fine !